# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a list of entities of type foo into table TB_FOO.

```
    Public Sub Insert(ByVal _lstFoo As List(Of TB_FOO))

    Try
      For i As Integer = 0 To _lstFoo.Count - 1
        Dim foo As TB_FOO = _lstFoo(i)        
        _MyEntityManager.AddToTB_FOO(foo)
      Next
      _MyEntityManager.SaveChanges()
      _MyEntityManager.AcceptAllChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

  End Sub
```

In the foo object there are 2 relationships. One is to the entity TB_FOO2 which is an object that was just inserted earlier in the code and another is TB_FOO3 which was selected from the database.

On the first iteration of the loop when it arrives to `_MyEntityManager.AddToTB_FOO(foo)` it throws the error

> An object with the same key already
>   exists in the ObjectStateManager. The
>   existing object is in the Unchanged
>   state. An object can only be added to
>   the ObjectStateManager again if it is
>   in the added state.

Any ideas why this error is thrown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably re-using an old `ObjectContext`.

This line:

```
_MyEntityManager.AddToTB_FOO(foo)
```

… Will fail if there is already an entity with the same primary key value as `foo` in the context. It will also fail if `foo` is related, via a navigation property, to some other entity which is detached, but which has a "twin" entity in the context with the same primary key value.

The simplest way to not have these problems is to use a new `ObjectContext` instance for the whole method and to dispose it when you're done. Long-lived `ObjectContext`s almost invariably lead to memory leaks and really confusing errors.

Comment: Apparently when I created the objects in _lstFoo I did Save and Accept All Changes for another object which in turn automatically did the inserts... Now I am saving after this method is called

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this because I have already created a new instance, and populated the properties I need to update.

```
Public Sub Insert(ByVal _lstFoo As List(Of TB_FOO))

Try
  For i As Integer = 0 To _lstFoo.Count - 1
    Dim foo As TB_FOO = _lstFoo(i) 
    ObjectStateEntry ose;  
    Dim key=CreateEntityKey("TB_FOOs",foo); 
    if(ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out ose)) then
       Dim entity=(TB_FOO)ose.Entity;
       TF_FOOs.Detach(entity);
    end if
    _MyEntityManager.AddToTB_FOO(foo)
  Next
  _MyEntityManager.SaveChanges()
  _MyEntityManager.AcceptAllChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
End Try

End Sub
```

this is a newer version of EF it seems, or just a different model. It's also translated from C# mostly, but hopefully it helps.